# Convert JDE Julian date (116175) to calendar date in OBIEE 11g Analysis

Tags: date, oracle11g, calendar, obiee, julian-date

I am trying to convert Julian date 116175 to calendar date in MM/DD/YYYY format in OBIEE 11g Analysis. Used below in Edit formula, but didn't work out.

cast("CycleCounts"."PJUPMJ" +1900000  as char)

Julian - 116175
Calendar Date - 6/23/2016

The result should really show as - 6/23/2016

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: So 'JDE Julian' not normal Julian; the first three digits are the year offset from 1900, and the last three digits are the day of the year? ([Or CYYDDD](http://www.kirix.com/stratablog/jd-edwards-date-conversions-cyyddd)). Are you looking for something that will run in the database, or only in the OBIEE layer?

Comment: I would like to convert at either OBIEE analysis or at rpd level

Comment: Anyone who can help me on this please ?

Comment: I could do an Oracle SQL solution but not familiar with OBIEE or rpd, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Decode (Nvl (119031, 0), 0, To_Date (Null),To_Date (To_Char (119031 + 1900000) , 'YYYYDDD')) From Dual
```

where 119031 is your date value